# Delete "Recently Deleted" album on iOS 8?

Tags: photos, ios

With iOS8, there was a new album called "Recently Deleted" in the Photos app. Is there any way to delete the "Recently Deleted" album or any way to disable this feature ?

I want the photos to get deleted as soon I delete them, I don't want to delete them twice. Jailbreak solutions are welcome too.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is jailbroken, you can install NoRecentlyDeleted, which does exactly what you would expect, making all photos be deleted immediately.